# Get free port list from switchshow command powershell

Tags: powershell

I am executing below code to get the free port from "switchshow" command

```
$lapw = Get-Content "E:\EncryptedPassword\storagepw.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content E:\EncryptedPassword\STORAGE_aes.key)
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("USER",$lapw)

$SAN_S = @(Get-Content -Path "E:\Storage\switches.txt")

foreach($SANs in $SAN_S)
{
$session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $SANs -Credential $cred

$Strem = New-SSHShellStream -SSHSession $Session

        $SystemView = $Strem.WriteLine("switchshow")  
        sleep -Seconds 5      
        $streamOut = $Strem.read() 
        sleep -Seconds 5
        $streamOut | Out-File -FilePath "E:\freeport\$SANs.txt" -Force
        
}
```

output I am getting like below

```
switchshow
============================================================================================
                                      ATTENTION:  
It is recommended that you change the default passwords for all the switch accounts.
Refer to the product release notes and administrators guide if you need further information.
============================================================================================

-----------------------------------------------------------------
sw02_New:USER> switchshow
switchName: sw02_New
switchType: 
switchState:    Online   
switchMode: Native
switchRole: Subordinate
switchDomain:   
switchId:   
switchWwn:  
zoning:     ON 
switchBeacon:   OFF
FC Router:  OFF
HIF Mode:   OFF
LS Attribute:

Index Port Address  Media Speed   State       Proto
==================================================
   0   0   0e0000   id    8G      No_Sync     FC  LS Disabled
   1   1   0e0100   id    N16     No_Light    FC     
  30  30   0e1e00   id    8G      Online      FC  LS E-Port  10:00:00:XX:XX:XX:XX:2X"
XXXXXXXXSW01" (upstream)
  48  48   0e3000   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port    
  49  49   0e3100   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port    
  50  50   0e3200   id    N16     No_Light    FC  
  51  51   0e3300   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port   
  67  67   0e4300   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port    
  68  68   0e4400   id    N16     No_Light    FC  
  69  69   0e4500   id    N16     No_Light    FC  
  70  70   0e4600   id    N16     No_Light    FC  
  71  71   0e4700   id    N16     No_Light    FC  
  72  72   0e4800   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  73  73   0e4900   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  74  74   0e4a00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  75  75   0e4b00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  76  76   0e4c00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  77  77   0e4d00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  78  78   0e4e00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  79  79   0e4f00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  80  80   0e5000   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  81  81   0e5100   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  82  82   0e5200   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  83  83   0e5300   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  84  84   0e5400   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  85  85   0e5500   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  86  86   0e5600   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  87  87   0e5700   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  88  88   0e5800   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  89  89   0e5900   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  90  90   0e5a00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  91  91   0e5b00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  92  92   0e5c00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  93  93   0e5d00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  94  94   0e5e00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
  95  95   0e5f00   --    N16     No_Module   FC  (No POD license) Disabled
sw02_New:USER>
```

I need to get all the lines where **State -ne "Online"** and put them in another text file

I was trying something like below, but not getting any output.

```
$All_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\freeport" -Filter "*.txt"

foreach($Files in $All_Files)
{

$File_Name = $Files.FullName
$result = switch -Regex -File $File_Name {
    '^\s*\d+:(.+)$' { 
        $values = ($matches[5].Trim() -split '\s+') -join ''
        if ($values -ne ('Online' * $values.Length)) { $_ }
    }
    default { $_ }
}
$Output_File = $Files.Name
$result | Set-Content -Path "E:\freeport\New_$Output_File"
}
```

Please need help in this. let me know incase you need any other information

Comment: Following check would do `(($_ -notmatch 'Online') -and ($_ -match '^\s+\d+')) { $_ }` This works for me for your example save in a tmp file `gc $env:temp\test.txt | ? {$_ -notmatch 'Online' -and $_ -match '^\s+\d+'}`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: It worked fine but not retained the header. any way to get the header also?

Comment: Add a `(...) -or ($_ -match '^Index Port')`

Answer (score 1):

@LievenKeersmaekers Thanks for your help. Below code helped resolving my issue.

There are multiple switches output so have to loop through.

```
$All_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\freeport" -Filter "*.txt"

foreach($Files in $All_Files)
{

$File_Name = $Files.FullName
$result = gc $File_Name | ? {($_ -notmatch 'Online' -and $_ -match '^\s+\d+') -or ($_ -match '^Index Port')}

$Output_File = $Files.Name
$result | Set-Content -Path "E:\freeport\New_$Output_File"
}
```

Comment: Nice, you can further shorten to this `{($_ -notmatch 'Online' -and $_ -match '^(\s+\d+|Index Port)')}`